# Paging an itemscontrol

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

i have a list of videos(Url+title) that is bound to an itemscontrol.For now i use a scrollviewer to scroll all the videos but i manage to page my itemscontrol.
This is my itemscontrol:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="_imageList"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,10,10"  Width="804"  >
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="5" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--<DataTemplate.Resources>
                <Image x:Key="image" Source="{Binding thumbnail}" />
            </DataTemplate.Resources>-->
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Button Grid.Row="0" Click="btn_Clicked" Margin="10,20,0,0" BorderThickness="0" Height="100" Width="200">
                    <Button.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding thumbnail}"  />
                    </Button.Background>
                </Button>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="nom" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding title}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Any ideas of how to do that?
this is the code behind

```
public void Images(int id)
    {
        var images = new ObservableCollection<Video>();
        var wcf = new ServiceReferenceVideo.VideoServiceClient();
        foreach (var item in wcf.GetKidVideos(id))
        {

            images.Add(item);
        }
        _imageList.ItemsSource = images;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Paging is currently not directly supported in an ItemsControl.

You may not page the View (and therefore the control) itself, but instead, page your video collection. You could implement a main collection with all your videos included. Now, if you want to page through this collection, one approach would be a second collection which is constantly getting cleared and filled with the next 10 items of the main collection.

You can pull a certain count of n items from your main collection (`images`) as follows:

```
ObservableCollection<Video> PageCollection = images.Take(n);
```

If you are not tied to the ItemsControl, you may have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/350447/WPF-Paging-in-DataGrid-ListBox) guide which is about paging for the DataGrid and ListBox control

Comment: i think i'm going to choose the first alternative ( a second collection).Could you please clarify more Mostey?

Comment: @RamiRaddaoui Did I left something unclear? What is unclear to you?